# Any way to re rospy.init_node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write an optimizer that launches many simulation ie. roslaunch.start()/shutdown()

If I init one node to subsrcibea and publish topics, after I shutdown the roslaunch sim, I signal_shutdown() the node. The next attempt to init that node doesn't work but issues no error. I do get a ROSInterruptexception when trying the call a publisher/subsriber (these are unregistered at the end of each sim run).

So I try to run roscore first and only issue one rospy.init_node before the roslaunch startup()/shutdown() loop. This seems to sort of work.
But I get a terminal full of TF_OLD_DATA errors and after a few runs the code crashes. I found answer suggesting running reset_time message but no such topic exists in indigo. It appears that while the im clock is reset with a new roslaunch, the tf buffer or some other sim time artifact still has the sim time from the previous run.

I can't be the only person running multiple sim runs. Please advise

---

Edit: I am trying to run simulations in sequence. Which I can do with import roslaunch module.

But rospy.init_doesn't like to be called a second time.

I have it working by running roscore first and then only one rospy.init_node and declaring subscribers and publishers then unregistering them each roslaunch. However, this generates many "TF_OLD_DATA" warnings ten times a second on the screen. Makes it hard to debug code.

sorr about duplicate new to ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249986/any-way-to-re-rospy.init_node/) by [robogrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/28791/robogrow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is that rospy and roscpp are not designed to initialize multiple times.

When I've wanted to do things like this, I usually run a separate ROS core for each simulation run, and the program that runs the simulation is generally not a ROS node. If you need to collect data from each run you could write it to a bag file or a custom data file and read that from your runner.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-01-22**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/185